# Let $U \in V$ be universes. Is $U-\bf Sp$ always $V-$complete?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, set-theory, stable-homotopy

Let $\bf Spaces_*$ and $\bf Sp$ denote the categories of pointed spaces and spectra.

Given two functors $F, G: \bf Spaces_* \to Sp$ I would like to define a *spectrum* of natural transformations. Usually this can be defined as $$\mathrm{nat}(F, G) :=  \text{lim}\bigg(\prod_{X}\mathrm{map}(F(X), G(X)) \rightrightarrows \prod_{X_0 \to X_1} \mathrm{map}(F(X_0), G(X_1))\bigg)$$

but in order to make sense, the requirement is that $\bf Spaces_*$ is small and $\bf Sp$ is complete. $\bf Sp$ is complete but of course $\bf Spaces_*$ is not small.

I heard that for avoiding such problems one usually introduces *Grothendieck universes*. Up to my understanding, one fixes a universe $U$ and declares the objects of $\bf Set$ to be the elements of $U$ and then constructs $\bf Spaces_*$ and $\bf Sp$ starting with this new category of sets. In $U$ the category $\bf Spaces_*$ is not small, but there is a universe $V$ such that $U \in V$ and in $V$ the category $\bf Spaces_*$ is small because $U$ is now a set. So we gained the smallness of $\bf Spaces_*$. But is $\bf Sp$ still complete?

**Question.** Let $U \in V$ be universes. Is $U-\bf Sp$ always $V-$complete?

I hope this question is well-posed, I am new to these concepts. Moreover I hope it is OK for MO.

Comment: Universes will not deliver a false statements. Assuming two universes $\Omega_1 \in \Omega_2$ is not much different from working with Sets and Classes, and the kind of statement you'll prove have the same taste. People love to use universes to cheat. If something is "a proper class" in the dichotomy Sets/Classes, then it belongs to $\Omega_1$ in the dichotomy $\Omega_0/\Omega_1$.

Comment: No, $U-\mathbf{Sp}$ is not $V$-complete. I don't think universes will help here, rather the idea of *accessible* functors might. Namely, if $F,G$ are determined by sufficiently small amount of data (namely, a set's worth), then you can get the usual machine rolling with no issues. This might sound like a limitation, but virtually all functors that will ever encounter are accessible (almost by design)

Comment: You can just regard your spectrum of natural transformations as being a $V$-spectrum rather than a $U$-spectrum.  The category of $V$-spectra is $V$-complete.